# which of the following exception handling code snippet is efficient and why

Tags: c++, exception

Which is efficient among the following code snippets

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   try
   {
   ...
   }
   catch ()
   {
   ...
   }
}
```

or

```
try
   { 
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
    ...
    }
   }
   catch ()
   {
   ...
   }
```

Comment: Not an apples for apples comparison. They have different execution paths, so the most efficient will be the one that suits you best.

Comment: They only have different paths if an exception is thrown; I assume he's asking about efficiency for the happy path.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "there's no difference" in most implementations, but if there were a difference, obviously the one that puts more code into the `for` loop is going to be less efficient, as the code generated for the `try` block (if there is any, and remember, generally there isn't) is going to be executed more times.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a `try`-`catch` block will come in the way of compiler optimizations. For example, any temporaries that are created within the loop will have a different scope (and thus different destruction semantics) should you introduce an exception handler. So, some/all [loop-optimizations](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci410/notes/loopOptEx.html) may not occur if you are going to put in any exception handling within the loop.